# Keep set number of decimal places while increasing by set amount

Tags: javascript, html, decimal

I have been making a timer that only counts decimals in intervals of 1/30 (so the only decimals are .x00, .x33, .x67).

So far it has been working pretty well, but something that drives me crazy is if the decimal is a multiple of 1/10, it shortens to .x when I want it to be .x00 (if that makes sense).

This causes the last two digits to blink rapidly and I believe that having the 00 on the end will make it smoother. I have this to display the output: `out.innerHTML = s+r.toFixed(3)*1;` (for reference).
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drj6fouw/)

Comment: Please share a [mre] here in the question.  The code in the fiddle also needs to be formatted so its readable.

Comment: `if (output.length < 2) output = '0'+output`

Comment: Why are you multiplying it by 1 to convert it back to a number? That is the problem. If `s` is a number you need to do the toFixed on the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out.innerHTML = (s+r).toFixed(3)
```

Parenthesis should do the trick.
It keeps the operator priority in the right order. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: why does that work? Variable s (for seconds) doesn't seem like it affects milliseconds, so why does it need toFixed?

Comment: In your example code, it first takes `r` and fixes it to 3 digits and converts to a string, then it multiplies by `1` which converts back into a number which automatically truncates the trailing `0`s. Then you add `s` to that number last. Really what you want is just to add `r` and `s` together and then to fix it to 3 places.

Answer (score 1):

Change `out.innerHTML = s+r.toFixed(3)*1` to `out.innerHTML = (s + r).toFixed(3)`.

The multiplication by 1 converts your value back to a number and then javascript converts that back to a string and truncates the trailing zeros.  Keeping your converted results as a string prevents the truncation.

Comment: You really need parenthesis around the `s+r` or you are going to risk getting unexpected results. Editing your answer to include them.

Comment: And, yes, safer, too.